# Ubuntu/Kubuntu LTS: longer support for server packages

Tags: security, kubuntu, updates, lts

I [read](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) that Ubuntu 10.04 LTS *Desktop* is supported till April 2013, but *Server* is supported till April 2015.

If I install Ubuntu LTS Desktop, will the server packages of the system still be updated until April 2015? I don't care about security updates to the desktop parts (the GUI for the server I'm setting up is rarely used, and not for anything dangerous like email and web browsing), but I do care about the server parts (like SSH, etc.).

And if so, would the same hold true for Kubuntu? The [LTS announcement](http://www.kubuntu.org/news/10.04-lts-release) naturally does not mention the longer server support window (seeing as to how it is a desktop distribution), but I wonder if the server packages will still get updates till 2015?

Comment: Yes, that should be the case. There is no Kubuntu server, or, in fact, also Ubuntu server in the sense of the preferred Desktop Environment. The Ubuntu project server edition has none, which means it shouldn't matter what GUI packages you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the server packages are what continues to receive updates.  How those packages got installed doesn't matter.  Note that if you want the kde desktop on a server, you might be better off installing the server edition, and then adding the kubuntu-desktop task instead of installing kubuntu, and then adding server packages.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Why would you say adding kubuntu-desktop on top of a server install is better?

Comment: @Lea Wiemann because you get to use the server installer, which is more flexible than the desktop installer, and helps set up all of the server packages for you.

Answer (score 0):

[From 12.04 onwards](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) both the server and desktop versions get the same support lifetime:

> A new LTS version is released every 2 years. In previous releases, a Long Term Support (LTS) version had 3 years support on Ubuntu (Desktop) and 5 years on Ubuntu Server. Starting with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, both versions will receive 5 years support. There is no extra fee for the LTS version; we make our very best work available to everyone on the same free terms. Upgrades to new versions of Ubuntu are and always will be free of charge.